# Static code analysis for VB6 and classic ASP

Tags: vb6, asp-classic, static-analysis

I'm looking for a static code analysis tool that will determine if I have orphaned functions in my VB6 code. The problem I'm running into is we make calls to the VB6 code from classic asp. Is there a tool that will look at both the classic asp and VB6 and determine if there are any orphaned functions?

Comment: How do you call VB6 functions from asp?Web services?

Comment: We use Server.CreateObject("DLL.Class")

Comment: This isn't an answer, but I bet it wouldn't be too much work to bang out a "poor man's" version using regex.  1st pass, gather all function names. 2nd pass, for each function name, find occurrences not preceded by "sub" or "function".

Answer (score 5):

Great Migrations offers a VB6/COM/ASP processor that can produce precisely what you are asking for. 
These detailed "reference reports" are a side benefit of the primary purpose of the product which is to help developers perform a custom, tool-assisted rewrite of large VB6/ASP/COM systems to the C#/ASPX/.NET platform.

It takes a little work to configure gmStudio to process an ASP site (i.e. you have to tell it which COM libraries to reference and which site files to load) but once given that information it can tell you exactly which members of COM libraries are actually referenced (and where, and how) a second report can tell you which members are not referenced (what you call "orphaned functions").

Visit the [Great Migrations site](http://www.greatmigrations.com) for details.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea there were such masochists in the world who would willingly devote their time and effort to stamping out VB6.  My hats off to them.

Comment: I have my doubts that my management will approve a $10,000 per user per month subscription...

Comment: Although .generating .NET code is blocked if you exceed license limits, generating reports is not.  So, one can use the free trial or promotional edition to do the analysis described.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the free [ASP Code Analyzer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11010/ASP-Code-Analyzer) tool on CodePlex.  It only has some basic analysis over unused functions and variables, but it's still useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use VBDepend for VB6 and VBA code, static analysis tool based on CQL, there are some of it's functionalities:

Compare Builds, 60 code metrics, manage Complexity and Dependencies